# swap tensor axis in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to swap tensor axis of image batches from (batch_size, row, col, ch) to 
(batch_size, ch, row, col).

in numpy, this can be done with

```
X_batch = np.moveaxis( X_batch, 3, 1)
```

How would I do that in Keras?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `K.permute_dimensions()` which is exactly similar to `np.transpose()`.

Example:

```
import numpy as np 
from keras import backend as K 

A = np.random.random((1000,32,64,3))
# B = np.moveaxis( A, 3, 1)
C = np.transpose( A, (0,3,1,2))

print A.shape
print C.shape

A_t = K.variable(A)
C_t = K.permute_dimensions(A_t, (0,3,1,2))

print K.eval(A_t).shape
print K.eval(C_t).shape
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `keras.layers.Permute(dims)` where `dims` [does not include the samples dimension](https://keras.io/layers/core/)

```
model.add(Permute((2, 1), input_shape=(10, 64)))
```