# How to transpose the output of each layer of keras and pass it to the next layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, data-science

How can I set the output of each layer of keras to be transposed(x.T) and then passed to the next layer?

For Example, layer1: x1= [[1,1,1],[2,2,2], w1= [[1,1,1],[2,2,2], out1 =x1*w1+b1.  ->>  layer2: x2=out1.T, w2= [[1,1,1],[2,2,2], out2 =x2*w2+b2.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.utils import normalize
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import tensorflow.keras.optimizers as optimizers
import tensorflow.keras.losses as losses
import tensorflow.keras.metrics as metrics
import numpy as np


mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)

model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do it. Could you check if this is your meaning?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878035/swap-tensor-axis-in-keras

Comment: Thanks. Good advice. But I need to do a lot of work to use it.

Comment: All of those transpose work is done by default when you use Dense layer of Keras, so I think you misunderstood this point when you think you need to transpose them manually.